# Is less than a month, 1 to 3 months, 3 to 6 months and so on... ordinal or scale?

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, scales

My questionnaire states "How long have you been going to the gym" and options include < 1 month, 1 - 3 months, 3 - 6 months and so on.
Ordinal or Scale?

Answer (score 1):

As is, it's ordinal. Almost certainly, a later choice is "over XXX months" and very probably the gaps increase in size (e.g. one of them is "1 to 2 years" or something like that).

With such scales, I have sometimes tried to transform it to a scale variable by using the midpoint of the intervals and adding random noise. If there is an upper unbounded interval, that will be a bit trickier.